# WSO2IS 5.10.0 - Missing user store properties in deployment.toml

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm migrating WSO2 Identity Server from version 5.8.0 to 5.10.0 and I'm missing some properties in deployment.toml file. On WSO2 documentation I couldn't find these properties from user-mgt.xml to put in deployment.toml file:

AnonymousBind 
TenantManager 
UserSearchBase 
UsernameJavaScriptRegEx 
PasswordJavaScriptRegEx 
RolenameJavaScriptRegEx

Have these properties been removed? [Documentation 5.10.0](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/setup/configuring-a-read-write-ldap-user-store/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following configs in `deployment.toml` file.

```
[user_store]
anonymous_bind = ""
user_search_base = ""
username_java_script_regex = ""
password_java_script_regex = ""
role_name_java_script_regex = ""
```

**UPDATED SECTION**

```
[user_store.properties]
IsBulkImportSupported = ""
EmptyRolesAllowed = ""
defaultRealmName=""
TenantManager = ""
```

Comment: Do you know if defaultRealmName, IsBulkImportSupported and EmptyRolesAllowed have the corresponding property too?